# Not uniform distribution of {nr} fractional parts

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Can a sequence like $\{n!\alpha\}$ or $\{(n!+1)\alpha\}$ (fractional parts), where $\alpha$ is irrational, be not uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$? I know about Weyl's result for polynomials $p(n)\cdot\alpha$.
David

Comment: Use latex. What do you get from the sequence $p_n/q_n$ in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2482261/276986) (it exists for example thanks to continued fractions) and from [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) in Diophantine approximation ?

Comment: @reuns I don't quite follow: the coefficients of continued fractions are very sparse, so how can they tell you much about equidistribution which concerns statistics across all $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The [standard proof that $e$ is irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational) rests on proving that $\{n!e\}$ lies strictly between $0$ and $1$, and in fact the estimate we get shows that it converges to $0$ (since it's strictly less than $\frac1n$), which makes it highly non-equidistributed.

Consequently, $\{(n!+1)e\} = \{n!e + e\}$ will converge to $\{e\} \approx 0.71828$ since $n!e$ is so close to an integer, so again it will be non-equidistributed.

Comment: O.K, this is one example. But is it typical in the Baire sense?

Comment: Also, what about $\{(n!+1)e\}$?

Comment: @Dave I would point out that your question only asks whether it *can* be non-equidistributed, not how often it is :).

Comment: @Dave Well, it shouldn't be hard to show that set of values that are as well-approximable as $e$ in this sense is uncountable and dense in $\mathbb R$.  But, I don't know whether it's first or second category.

Comment: @Dave See Gerry Myerson's answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944292/30402.  I lack the context to be sure of what the quoted section is referring to, but it does seem that Weyl already considered this question and proved that the non-equidistributed set has measure zero, so it's not typical.